# NTLM Handshake rejected: CURL

Tags: curl, ntlm

I am running the curl command in order to get information from a windows 2012 server from a linux machine. Every time, I get an NTLM Handshake rejected error. Has this problem been encountered before? Is it solvable?

Answer (score 1):

did you try --anyauth option?
E.g.

```
curl https://someausomewebsite.come/countriesapi/ -v --ntlm --anyauth -u baba:secret
```